# selelct2 autocomplete not showing values from database

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

This is my code. Callback function shows undefined value.[In image You can see I am getting undefined values which are initially fetched from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEXVB.jpg)

THis is HTML

```
<input type="text" name="city[]" class="itemSearch form-control" id="city_dropdown" value='{{$cities}}'>
```

PHP CODE:
     $cities = $this->city->select('city_name', 'id')->whereIn('id', $city)->get()->toArray();
            $cities = json_encode($cities);

I get this  [{"city_name":"Badarpur Railway Town","id":321},{"city_name":"Bahbari Gaon","id":322}]  in $cities. which is a value of HTML text box.

```
 $("#city_dropdown").select2({
      minimumInputLength: 2,
      tags: [],
      ajax: {
          url: adminPath+"pincode/getcitydropdown",
          dataType: 'json',
          type: "GET",
          quietMillis: 50,
          data: function (term) {
              return {
                  term: term
              };
          },
          results: function (data) {
              return {
                  results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                      return {
                          text: item.city_name,
                          id: item.id
                      }
                  })
              };
          }
      }, initSelection : function (element, callback) {
         var elementText = $(element).attr('value');
          callback(JSON.parse(elementText));
      }

  });
```

Comment: check what data is coming for `item.city_name` by doing an alert.

Comment: Add the PHP code too.

Comment: @prava I have added PHP too

Comment: @prava the problem is i am not able to get the initial value from database. it does work when user type something and it provides suggestions too.

Comment: @Sougata I am processing data in some php file

Comment: @Sougata I have added that code too.